# Booting into Linux on Dell XPS takes me to OS Assist Screen Everytime

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, dell

I have a Dell XPS I recently partitioned a drive on the machine to have a Linux distribution and I was able to boot into it from the boot menu (ie. Spam F12 on restart and then Select which disk I want to boot onto). This worked fine for a while if I wanted windows I could boot into Windows if I wanted Linux I would select that partition and boom Linux would be booted into. Recently this behavior no longer works, whenever I try to boot into my linux partition I am taken immediately to some disk health check screen (a Dell Tool that runs on a failed boot apparently). I let the scan run and it basically came back with a warning for me that no Windows boot files were found on this parition (go figure it's because it's for Linux). What can I do to boot into my Linux Partition I've considered just installing a new Linux distro and then overwriting whatever is on that drive but I'm hesitant to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Edit

I am using kubuntu

Comment: It was an Ubuntu distro

Comment: And what does "*Ubuntu distro*" mean to you; you've still not given us any details so we're limited in how we can help you. Do you mean a Ubuntu Core server system? Ubuntu Server system? Ubuntu Desktop system?  Ubuntu *flavor* system?  what release of whatever Ubuntu product you installed. Currently we have no details as your question asks about Linux & Windows; neither being on-topic here.  Edit your question & add details there, as comments for us to ask you things; comments will get removed when questions are altered & details are known.

Comment: edited to include answer

Comment: We now know it's a Kubuntu (Ubuntu desktop *flavor*) but not what release you're asking about. Ubuntu Desktop releases are *year.month* in format, eg. Kubuntu 22.04 LTS is the 2022-April release; which are you asking about?